# Visual studio 2019 window not showing

Tags: window, visual-studio-2019

After a windows update, my visual studio 2019 does not open window, i can see it in the task bar but even if i click on the visual studio icon it does not expand and show me the IDE. i look at the event view logs and see the following error:

The program devenv.exe version 16.8.30717.126 stopped interacting with Windows and was closed. To see if more information about the problem is available, check the problem history in the Security and Maintenance control panel.
Process ID: 6790
Start Time: 01d6c5c56f111d56
Termination Time: 4294967295
Application Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Report Id: 75bec9b7-5f93-4733-b901-f93aaef46666
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:
Hang type: Top level window is idle

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

One solution i found for showing the IDE window was to hover over the visual studio icon, and then when you see the minimized version of the window, right click on it and select the following option: [image]

This however does not solve the problem for why its not expanding normally.

Comment: Does any of the other options under *Send window to* bring VS to the active desktop? It may just be opening off-screen due to mis-remembering the last position, or perhaps a monitor/docking/etc change.

Comment: all options under send window are disabled.